# Compare Eigenvector Centrality of two networks

Tags: eigenvalues, networks

We have two networks (G1, G2), one with 4 times more nodes than the other, and we want to compare the eigenvector centrality of their three most central nodes (e.g. top_1 node of G1 vs top_1 node of G2).

How should we normalize the eigenvector centrality scores to account for the difference in node size between networks?